# In PyDev, how do I refactor a local variable into an attribute?

Tags: python, pydev

I need to break up a method that uses several local variables and make those variable available to the new methods as attributes. I thought I would be able to use refactoring to rename each local variable by adding `self.` to the front. Unfortunately, PyDev disagrees with me! Is there a way to get PyDev to do what I want?

Comment: Perhaps it is better to pass them around as parameters and return values, not promote them to object state?

Comment: Yeah, I'd think about whether this is a good idea, depends on your specific circumstances obviously, but it sounds a little bit more like defactoring than refactoring. There's probably a better way to break up your functions than stuffing more attributes in your class. It sounds like they're too tightly coupled if you're having to do this.

Comment: These are PyUnit methods that need to share things from `setUp()`.

Comment: Are you creating and defining them in setUp() as well as changing the names in your methods? Posting a very small example that's not working for you would be helpful.